# python windows how to forcefully exit or join a thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

What i'm trying to do this run a function on a thread and start a timer and then forcefully join or exit the thread once a certain duration has been reached, now i have been informed that this can be done in linux but i don't know the equivalent to windows so i did this:

```
#idea is to want to run the function for 7 secs but it will stop at 5 secs
import time
import threading
def func():
   for i in range(0,7):#print not yet done 7 times
      print("not yet done")
      time.sleep(1)
t1=threading.Thread(target=func())

timer=time.perf_counter
while t1.join()==False:#loop while function is not done
   if timer>5:#stop function at 5 seconds
      print(timer)
      print("done")
      t1.join()
```

Comment: It should be the same, regardless of the OS underneath. What did you try? What is the solution for Linux that you think doesn't work? That said, there's a very obvious bug in above code which has nothing to do with interrupting threads. Use a debugger to step through it (there are video tutorials for that) to easily find it. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: i used signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler) but according to people it's only available in UNIX, i also tested this and it wouldn't work on my computer